# OutofMemoryException thrown while scrolling a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, out-of-memory, fatal-error

If we are scrolling the `Listview` quickly the app throws a Fatal Exception `OutofMemoryError`.

It always gives the same error while scrolling. How to handle it?

```
public class UpcomingAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Typeface typeFace;
    private ArrayList<String> mEventName,mDate,mTime;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public UpcomingAdapter(LayoutInflater mInflater,
                           ArrayList<String> mDEventName,
                           ArrayList<String> mDdate,
                           ArrayList<String> mDtime,
                           Typeface typeface)
    {
        this.mEventName=mDEventName;
        this.mDate=mDdate;
        this.mTime=mDtime;       
        this.mInflater=mInflater;
        this.typeFace=typeface;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(view==null) {
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.upcomingevent_list,null);
            view.setTag(holder);
            holder=(ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            holder.holderDate=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.xTvUpcomingEvents_DateList);
            holder.holderEventName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.xTvUpcomingEvents_Events);
            holder.holderEventName.setTypeface(typeFace);
            holder.holderDate.setTypeface(typeFace);
        } else {
            holder=(ViewHolder) view.getTag();  
        }

        //holder.employeeName.setTag(mEmpIds.get(arg0));
        setText(mEventName.get(arg0), holder.holderEventName);
        setText(mDate.get(arg0), holder.holderDate);
        setText(mTime.get(arg0), holder.holderEventName);

        holder.holderEventName.setTag(mEventName.get(arg0));
        holder.holderEventName.setTypeface(typeFace);

        //holder.holderArtistId.setTypeface(typeFace);

        return view;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        TextView holderEventName;
        TextView holderDate;

        //TextView holderArtistId;
    }

    private void setText(String data,TextView view){
        if(data.equals(StaticUtils.sNullString)){
            view.setText(StaticUtils.sEmptyString);
        } else {
            view.setText(data);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
08-17 15:08:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25423): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 15:08:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25423): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]
08-17 15:08:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25423):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your getView Method try:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View view, ViewGroup parent) {


        if(view==null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.upcomingevent_list, parent, false);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.holderDate=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.xTvUpcomingEvents_DateList);
            holder.holderEventName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.xTvUpcomingEvents_Events);
            holder.holderEventName.setTypeface(typeFace);
            holder.holderDate.setTypeface(typeFace);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder=(ViewHolder) view.getTag();  
        }

        //holder.employeeName.setTag(mEmpIds.get(arg0));
        setText(mEventName.get(arg0), holder.holderEventName);
        setText(mDate.get(arg0), holder.holderDate);
        setText(mTime.get(arg0), holder.holderEventName);

        holder.holderEventName.setTag(mEventName.get(arg0));
        holder.holderEventName.setTypeface(typeFace);

        //holder.holderArtistId.setTypeface(typeFace);

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the 
onLowMemory() method of activity, and run the garbage collector, when the activity detects low memory.
You can use System.gc(). Also nullify the unwanted variables in this method.

Answer (score -2):

**Replace below method with your existing code.**

```
   @Override
        public int getItem(int position) {
            return <Return Particular int variable from Data>;
        }

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return <Return Particular int variable from Data>;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return <Return Particular int variable from Data>;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is absolutely wrong, as you are saying that everything from your perspective returns same `int variable`.